# C++ Launching programs with system() not giving desired results

Tags: c++, windows, launcher

I have a C++ code setup that launches items for me, all i have to do is input the name and it launches. The Problem is that when I have the C++ Application launch it the C++ Application "turns into it" By that i mean pretend i'm using it launch a minecraft server. It will act as if the minecraft server was were it was and its make files it needs there Not using the ones in its directory. If anyone can help please do.

(Heres the code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string textin;
    cin >> textin;
    if ( textin == "ATLauncher" ) {
        system("C:\\users\\USER\\Main\\minecraftserver\\minecraftserver.exe");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to change the working directory before launching.  Working within posix, the call you want is `chdir(path)`.   Make that call before the system call.

Note that Windows stores the working directory elsewhere (in the shortcut link) so you may need to look at that to determine the correct path.

Comment: Could you show me how to do that, im not used to C++ or anything thats not HTML.

Comment: On Windows, `system` runs the target using `%COMSPEC% /c`. Usually `COMSPEC` is the default cmd.exe shell, which has a built-in [`start` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx) that has a `/d` switch that sets the working directory. This way you don't have to first [`_chdir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx) in the parent.